# read variable and trigger event - python

Tags: python, python-3

I have the following script which increases the `counter` variable every time a button is pressed. When `counter` reaches a certain number i.e. 10 lets say I want an event to trigger.

```
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

button1=22

GPIO.setup(button1,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

counter = 0

while(1):
        if GPIO.input(button1)==0:
                counter = counter + 1
                sleep (0.5)
                print counter
        if counter == 10:
                print("target reached")

GPIO.cleanup()
```

I've been informed that a simple way to do this would be check the counter each time it changes and then use an `if` statement to trigger the event. Unfortunately I have a very elementary understanding of programming and have little idea how to do this.

Having researched `if` statements I came across this one that looked as if it might work -

```
if counter == 10:
  print("target reached")
```

It runs without error but doesn't do anything when expected.

My question therefore is how to proceed from here?

Thanks

Comment: I didn’t see this last edit to your code, but I would have expected it to work, for what that’s worth.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I actually used the code you answered with however I needed to indent the `sleep` line as the counting was proving a little unpredictable as it was. Seems to be working OK now.

Comment: Ahhh!! Got it.  I didn't realize that sleep was probably to catch longer presses.  Glad you got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(1):
        if GPIO.input(button1)==0:
                counter = counter + 1
                print counter
                if counter == 10:
                    print “I did it!”
                sleep(0.5)  # to prevent multiple counts
```